# How do I create thumbnails with lower resolution images in html

Tags: php, html, web, gallery, thumbnails

I have a bunch of high resolution images (like 6000x4000 jpegs) and i've made a 3-column gallery with them (looks something like unsplash's gallery). So i want it to be a gallery with low res thumbnails and when i click on them i have the full res image opened in new tab. I've set the width of divs containing imgs to 400px with css, but it only affects their appearance in page layout. I mean in those 400px divs images that are loaded are still 6000x4000, so page freezes when i scroll. And i want to load low resolution images in those divs but without creating another folder with every jpg in low resolution and load them istead. i mean can i lower the resolution of images that are loaded into the page using html, css, js, jquery, php?

Answer (score 1):

If you already loaded the image to client side, there is no real point in lowering the resolution, you should use a server side solution to generate small images than, loading will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question would be: No, there is no way to alter image resolution with HTML, CSS or JavaScript.

A proper solution would be to resize your images before deploying them on the server: create one version 400px width and keep the source.

Afterwards you can use the small version for your gallery (as thumbnails) and wrap those in a link pointing to the sourcefile.

That way noone has to load those huge images when visiting the gallery, as pageweight is drastically reduced and on click users can then download the original image (I'd still recommend putting some kind of warning in front of this as 6000x4000 sounds like an awful lot of data even for a single image).

Example:

```
<figure>
    <a href="path/to/huge-source.jpg">
        <img src="path/to/thumbnail.img" alt="Some alternative text" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>Beware: the link points to a source file with a lot of data to download (resolution: 6000x4000)</figcaption>
<figure>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i forgot to add that i also know basics of php. is there a way to do that using php?

Comment: Check the PHP docs: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php there are a ton of possible solutions.